# Why does this code always return file size zero?

Tags: c++, file, binary, fstream, operation

Why, when I use following code snippet the result is zero regardless of the file size, but when I remove `ios::binary` in `open()` it does what it's supposed to do?

```
fstream f1;    
streampos begin, end;
f1.open("file1", ios::binary);
f1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
begin = f1.tellg();
f1.seekg(0, ios::end);
end = f1.tellg();
f1.close();
cout << end - begin << endl;
```

Comment: It honestly baffles me how people can write code that doesn't check for error conditions. Just.... why?!

Answer (score 8):

I assume that by "when I remove `ios::binary`" you mean you remove the entire argument:

```
f1.open("file1");
```

The function [`open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) has two parameters - file name and mode. The mode one has a default argument of `std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out`. So if you don't specify anything, this deault gets used.

If you specify `ios::binary`, however, you *replace* the default argument. And since you have specified neither `in` nor `out`, the `open()` call fails. Putting an `if()` around the `open()` would tell you — remember you should always check for error with I/O.

Comment: Haha... a beautiful demonstration of why error checking is important.

Comment: thanx Angew but why this code works?
`ifstream myfile ("example.bin", ios::binary);`

Comment: @MojtabaKarimdokht It's obvious you're going to use `std::basic_ifstream` for input so the constructor calls `open` on the buffer through `rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::in)` where mode is `ios_base::binary` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

`std::ios_base::binary` by itself is not a valid openmode for `std::basic_fstream`. The valid openmode combinations can be found on Table 132:

> [image]

The constructor of `std::basic_fstream` and its `open()` method both forward the `open()` method on the internal `std::basic_filebuf` through `rdbuf()->open(s, mode)` where `mode` is the openmode. As you can see from the table, `mode` (where mode is `ios_base::binary`) by itself is not a valid flag. When the file buffer determines this the open fails:

> The NTBS `modstr` is determined from `mode & ~ios_base::ate` as indicated in Table 132. If `mode` is not some combination of flags shown in the table then the open fails.

The reason `mode` isn't bitwise-OR'ed with `out | in` when opening the file is because it's not clear whether you want to use the stream for input or output (it assumes you know what you want). Since the mode isn't a valid flag combination, `std::basic_filebuf::open()` returns a null pointer. This is picked up by the stream which in turn calls `setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)`.

> [..] calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode)`. If that function returns a null pointer, calls `setstate(failbit)`.

When a stream is in a fail state its `tell` methods return `-1`. That's why you're getting `0` when subtracting.

This is the correct way to open it if all you want is the size:

```
std::fstream f1("file1", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::ate | std::ios_base::binary);
std::cout << f1.tellg();
```

Comment: Oh my god!  I didn't know that problem has this complicated long scary background! :O

Answer (score 0):

If you get a size of 0, check to see if the file opened...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    fstream f1;
    streampos begin, end;
    f1.open("Data.txt", ios::binary);
    if (f1.is_open()) {
        cout << "Open" << endl;
    }
    f1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    begin = f1.tellg();
    f1.seekg(0, ios::end);
    end = f1.tellg();
    f1.close();
    cout << end - begin << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

If it didn't open, you may have tried opening a text file.

In text files the ios::binary flag is not included in opening mode. Text files are for storing text data and when binary input/output operations are tried on them, this can result in formatting transformations.

Comment: What makes you think opening any file in binary mode is a problem? Binary mode is the norm. Text mode only exists to translate platform-specific line-ending characters into `'\n'` on reading, and back again on writing. A file itself is just (binary) data on disk.

Comment: When I try opening a text file with the binary flag, file.is_open() returns false. When that flag is removed, the file opens.

Comment: What OS and filesystem? Must be a pretty exotic combination to differentiate binary and text files like this. Or are you doing the same error as the OP and passing *just* `ios::binary` to a `fstream::open()` (without either `ios::in` or `ios::out`)?